# Snapshot isolation transaction aborted due to update conflict

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, transactions, transaction-isolation, snapshot-isolation

Following statement:

```
INSERT INTO dbo.Changes([Content], [Date], [UserId], [CompanyId]) 
  VALUES (@1, @2, @3, @4);
SELECT @@identity;
```

gives me this SQL error 3960:

> Snapshot isolation transaction aborted due to update conflict. You
>   cannot use snapshot isolation to access table 'dbo.Companies' directly
>   or indirectly in database 'myDatabase' to update, delete, or insert
>   the row that has been modified or deleted by another transaction.
>   Retry the transaction or change the isolation level for the
>   update/delete statement.

As far as I understood, from the error message, I should not update, delete, or insert to table `dbo.Companies` during the time another connection is modifying `dbo.Companies`.

But why it occurs when I was inserting a new row to another table `dbo.Changes` (which has foreign key to `dbo.Companies`) and I was not deleting the referenced row in `dbo.Companies`, but I was just updating row in `dbo.Companies` and not the primary key? This should work ok, shouldn't it? (Is it a bug in SQL Server?)

**UPDATE:**

Tables looks like following:

```
dbo.Changes([Id] int PK, [Content] nvarchar, 
  [Date] datetime, [UserId] int, [CompanyId] int -> dbo.Companies.[Id])
dbo.Companies([Id] int PK, [Name] nvarchar)
```

Second update is doing:

```
UPDATE dbo.Companies WHERE [Id] = @1 SET [Name] = @2;
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It appears SQL Server **will acquire update locks** on any record it has to read **even if it doesn't modify it**.

More info on this [microsoft.public.sqlserver.server thread](https://groups.google.com/d/topic/microsoft.public.sqlserver.server/x8yrxL5Ytxc/discussion):

> Without a supporting index on CustomerContactPerson, the statement
>
> DELETE FROM ContactPerson WHERE ID = @ID;
>
> Will require a "current"
>   read of all the rows in CustomerContactPerson to  ensure that there
>   are no CustomerContactPerson rows that refer to the  deleted
>   ContactPerson row. With the index, the DELETE can determine that 
>   there are no related rows in CustomerContactPerson without reading the
>   rows  affected by the other transaction.
>
> Additionally, in a snapshot
>   transaction the pattern for reading data which  you are going to turn
>   around and update is to take an UPDLOCK when you  read. This ensures
>   that you are making your update on the basis of  "current" data, not
>   "consistent" (snapshot) data, and that when you issue  the DML, it the
>   data won't be locked, and you won't unwittingly overwrite  another
>   session's change.

The fix for us was **adding indexes to the foreign keys**

In your example, I suspect adding an index to Changes.CompanyId will help. I'm not sure if this is a real solution. Can the SQL Server optimizer choose not to use the index?

Comment: Thank you for hints, but it does not seem to help.

Comment: Do both statements (INSERT and UPDATE) refer to the same Customer? If so, we are out of luck as far as I know.

Comment: Yes, insert is using id of currently updating company.

Comment: Reading through (the long) dbaspot thread, it sounds like this is a limitation of SQL Server. The indexes in this answer will only help where the two statments involve different Customers.

Comment: Thanks, happened to have a table with dozen FKs noone cared to create indexes, after creating the missing indexes got no more errors like that so far.

Comment: I have the same issue with my SP , and I have below statement in my SP , SELECT somecolumn FROM Sometable s WITH (UPDLOCK)
Sometable is being updated in the same SP , isolation level is set as SNAPSHOT or database level and in C# transaction are using SNAPSHOT isolation level , NO isolation level specified in the SP , what to do ??

Comment: I've added indexes in an attempt to fix my issue using this case, hoping it would work, but did not appear to do anything to resolve the issue by itself

Answer (score 3):

SQL Server can see an update to a dependent table which COULD modify the behavior of the insert ... seems fair to me as SQL can not guess what other logic might be dependent on the [name] column (triggers etc.)

if your applications implement deadlock retry logic you can modify them to treat error no 3960 the same as error no 1205 and automatically retry ...

Comment: You make a good point.... except, I still don't get why having a non clustered, non unique index on the related table's foreign key column is enough to make this not happen - i.e. is it not the case that it still could modify the behaviour of the insert, even with the index?

Comment: @Kram I suppose the index helps granularity. Engine knows a dependent table needs to be locked but without a index it can try to lock the entire table instead a single row