# What isolation level does autocommit transaction use in SQL Server?

Tags: c#, sql-server, transactions, ado.net

When I work with update conflict problem with SNAPSHOT Isolation Level, it seems that autocommit transactions use the isolation level used at last time.

Condition: ALLOW_SNAPSHOT_ISOLATION is ON, READ_COMMITTED_SNAPSHOT is OFF

**Step 1 : Execute update statement without transaction**

```
using (var sqlconn = new SqlConnection("Data source=..."))
using (var sqlcmd = sqlconn.CreateCommand())
{
    sqlconn.Open();
    sqlcmd.CommandText = "Update ..."
    sqlcmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

Then I take a look in `sys.md_exec_sessions` and found the transaction isolation level is `READCOMMITTED`.

**Step 2 : Execute update statement with transaction in SNAPSHOT isolation level**

```
using (var sqlconn = new SqlConnection("Data source=..."))
{
    sqlconn.Open();

    using (var sqltran = sqlconn.BeginTransaction(IsolationLevel.Snapshot))
    using (var sqlcmd = sqlconn.CreateCommand())
    {
        sqlconn.Open();
        sqlcmd.CommandText = "Update ..."
        sqlcmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
}
```

The isolation level is `Snapshot`, works good.

**Step 3 : do step 1 again**

The isolation level is `Snapshot`.
I expect step 3 shows `READCOMMITTED` cause READ_COMMITTED_SNAPSHOT  is OFF.

There is two ideas that I supposed, but I cannot conclude.

1. dm_exec_sessions will not contains information about autocommit transactions
2. autocommit transaction actually uses `SNAPSHOT`

Any idea will be appreciated.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't a specific isolation level for autocommit transactions. They use whatever isolation level has last been declared for a connection (or the server default).

Unfortunately, however, in the face of connection pooling<sup>1</sup>, what you think of as a "new" connection may in fact be a re-used one. So in some circumstances, you'll pick up a connection that uses an isolation level different from the SQL Server default (Read Committed).

My advice would be - if you use explicit isolation levels anywhere, you also need to make sure that you use *different* connection string, or you need to turn *off* connection pooling, if you don't want to explicitly set the isolation level *everywhere*. I'd usually prefer the first, so that you can still benefit from connection pooling, but have separate pools for each required isolation level.

<sup>1</sup> [Connect Issue](https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/243527/sp-reset-connection-doesnt-reset-isolation-level) which seems to indicate that this may or may not be true for SQL Server 2014 and later.