# Conflicted transactions

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework

I have this error when my some transactions conflicted. How can i find what is the thansaction in conflict? (Without sql server profiler).

I am using snapshot isolation level

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Snapshot isolation transaction
> aborted due to update conflict. You cannot use snapshot isolation to
> access table 'dbo.Users' directly or indirectly in database
> 'IUMobileDbRelease' to update, delete, or insert the row that has been
> modified or deleted by another transaction. Retry the transaction or
> change the isolation level for the update/delete statement.
>
> ```
>     System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.SaveChanges()
> ```

Comment: You use SQL Server Profiler. Or Extended Events, the replacement of profiler. Better yet, just *don't* use transactions. Use optimistic concurrency instead. That's the standard advice since the 1990s. Code that uses transactions *can't* scale and will *always* have to handle deadlocks and retry. Since the 1990s, applications use optimistic concurrency and rowversion columns to detect conflicting changes *without* using transactions

Comment: The other option is to use the SNAPSHOT transaction isolation level instead of repeatable read. It's slower than optimistic concurrency but ensures you won't get any deadlocks unless two applications try to modify the same row

Comment: which SQL server version is it? consider this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/33272566/1132334

Comment: @dlatikay all current versions support this (ie SQL Server 2012 and later). It's still slower than optimistic concurrency

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos i am already use snapshot isolation

Comment: @GLeBaTi first, without the *query* it's impossible to help. It's not the server that caused the deadlock, it's the query or queries, the number of records the affect and the duration of the transaction. A transaction should be used **only** to save the modified data and committed immediatelly. Keeping a transaction open for the duration of a request is a common mistake. There is a reason that optimistic concurrency is preferred. Do you use an explicit transaction or the implicit transaction used by `SaveChanges()`?

Comment: I want find slow transaction from my many transactions (~100 different transactions). How can i do this? Can i do this by information from exception?

Comment: not a 100% duplicate, but part of the "how can I find... ?" seems to be answered here already: http://stackoverflow.com/a/20757916/1132334

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In EF6, you can enable query logging:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn469464(v=vs.113).aspx

For example:

```
context.Database.Log = Console.Write;
```

Correlate its output with the exception you get, to narrow it down to a statement.